# Unable to unesape consecutive escape char in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml()

Tags: java, xml, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3, stringescapeutils

Unable to unescape consecutive escape char like **&lt;errors&gt;**.
Below is the sample code:

```
    String error = "&amp;lt;errors&amp;gt;";
    String out = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(error);
    System.out.println(out);
```

Current Output: `&lt;errors&gt;`

Expected output: `<errors>`

This code ran on JDK 11.0.16 version
and commons-lang3-3.4.jar version.

Comment: If  you expect ```&<errors&>```Your error string is malformned, ```lt;``` and ```gt;``` aren't html entities.

Comment: My expectation is <errors> as output.

Comment: correct encode string: ```&lt;errors&gt;```. ```&amp;``` doesn't matter in this context.

Comment: `&amp;` is escape for `&`, so ..you expect "double unescape": `&amp;lt;errors&amp;gt;` -> `&lt;errors&gt;` -> `<errors>`

Comment: Agree to run many times. But I Suprised was in one of my environments this is working. There ran on JDK1.8. However, it's not working as a standalone application JDk (1.8 and JDK11) as well. something is weared. Though JDK upgrade issue but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unescape the String as many times as the input String has been escaped.

```
var input = "&amp;lt;errors&amp;gt;";
var output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(input);
output = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(output);
System.out.println(output);
```